# a href loses relative directory in Jade in Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My Express web app has a Jade view which contains a  element.

The current URL is `http://localhost:3000/location`. This page has a list of locations, each of which is represented by a ID in a hyperlink, e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/location/1
http://localhost:3000/location/4
http://localhost:3000/location/202
```

In the location.jade, my code is

```
ul#locList
    for location in jsonData
      li
        a(href='#{location.locationid}')
          h2 #{location.locationname} (#{location.locationid})
```

The generated hyperlink is http://localhost:3000/1.

I don't want to hardcode "location/" in the view. How can I get the relative directory in the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full url path from server side and send it the view using the respective route `req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl`